# How to evaluate post value from the constructor codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good Day,

I have a constructor function that checks if the user is login or not..

code:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');

    if (!logged_in()) {
        redirect('/');
        die;
    };
 }
```

now I want to add another condition so I can still access my methods on the controller class even its not logged in, like I want to pass a key for a simple validation..

I tried to get the form value by adding `$this->input->post('key')` inside the constructor.

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $key = $this->input->post('key');
        echo $key;
        die;

    if (!logged_in() OR $key==null) {
        redirect('/');
        die;
    };
 }
```

so the condition will be come if not logged in OR $key is null then it will redirect to login page, but it always returns empty or null. how do I properly do this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $key = $this->input->post('key');

    if(!logged_in() || (logged_in() && $key=='')) {
      redirect('/');
      die;
    }
}
```